HAproxy TCP proxy depending on the subdomain for databases
I'm trying to do a proxy with Haproxy to fordward TCP request depending on the subdomain.
Example :
psql -h dev1.mydomain.com -p 8888 --> haproxy proxy --> 192.168.49.2:33333
psql -h dev2.mydomain.com -p 8888 --> haproxy proxy --> 192.168.49.2:33334

but I have issue with the SSL part, my haproxy file :
global
    log /dev/log local0
    log /dev/log local1 notice
    ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3
    ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305
    ssl-dh-param-file /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

frontend db_frontend
    bind :8888 ssl crt /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.dev/mydomain.dev.pem
    mode tcp
    log global
    option tcplog
    tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
    tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
    timeout client 1m
    
    acl acl-test-first req_ssl_sni -i  devpg.mydomain.dev
    use_backend db_test_first if acl-test-first
    
    acl acl-test-second req_ssl_sni -i test.mydomain.dev
    use_backend db_example if acl-test-second

backend db_test_first
    mode tcp
    log global
    server db_server_1 192.168.49.2:31835
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 1m

backend db_test_second
    mode tcp
    log global
    server db_server_2 192.168.49.2:31587
    timeout connect 10s
    timeout server 1m

I enable ssl on my postgresql db.
error when i try to connect to the db :
root@my-user:# psql -h devpg.mydomain.dev -p 8888 -d mydb -U myuser -W
Password: 
psql: error: server closed the connection unexpectedly
        This probably means the server terminated abnormally
        before or while processing the request.

And on haproxy log :
Apr  9 14:45:55 my-user haproxy[644608]: 192.168.1.1:37330 [09/Apr/2024:14:45:55.120] db_frontend/1: SSL handshake failure
I want this because i will have many db in the future, and want to contact them using the subdomain  and not a port.
Is it possible with HAproxy ?
thanks
